# Why is `main` called twice here?

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

Here is my code:

```
public class Test
{
   static 
   {
      main(null);
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      System.out.println("done");
   }
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
done 
done
```

Can somebody please explain me the reason for this?

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think unusual? The `static` block is executed once when the class is loaded (and it has to be loaded before executing `main` method. Then the `main` method itself is executed.

Check out this modified version:

```
public class Test {
    static {
        main(new String[]{"[done static]"});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "[done]");
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
[done static]
[done]
```

Comment: we are passing null as argument in main method present in static,it should be string

Comment: I am getting only confused due to null argument present in  main method  inside static block,please tell me that will it  create any problem or not, because main method expect a String type as argument

Comment: @saurabhRai: `main` method expectes `String` **array**, not a `String`. Also the `null` is not quite correct because the `main` method is always supplied with arguments array by the JVM - and if there are no arguments, this array is empty, but not `null`.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that `main` is called twice:

1. Explicitly, from the [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) as soon as the class is loaded.
2. Implicitly, on program entry as soon as the program starts.

How to fix this? Either don't call it explicitly or rename it so that it won't be called automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Because

- the `static { ... }` part is called when the class `Test` is loaded inside the JVM (it's a sort of static constructor)
- while the `main` method is called when the execution begins.

Answer (score 1):

The static block of a class is invoked when the class is first loaded. That is the first done. The second one is because you are running the program and then the main method is invoked.

Comment: whatever you are telling me that i know but the question is ,we are passing null as argument in main method present in static ,it should have some string

Comment: Since you are not using the parameters passed to main it does not matter what you are passing to main method. It will just be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The main is automatically called by the virtual machine when it loads the jar. So this is the first 'Done', the normal entry point for a Java program.

The second 'Done' is written because you explicitly call it in the static class initializer. The 'static' section that you added to your 'Test' class is called as soon as your class is loaded by the virtual machine class loader.

The one should from the static initializer even be called before the entry point Main is called, as the class needs to be loaded before the entry point is called.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `Test.main`, JVM needs to initialize the `Test` class by running its static initializer. This call is responsible for the first call of `main()`. Once the initialization is complete, JVM calls `main()` again, ultimately producing the output that you see.

Answer (score 1):

Main is automatically called by JVM. There is not need to call it in a static section.

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      System.out.println("done");
   }
}
```

The above code is what it should be.